# How to interpret Hadith about Universe creation

Tags: hadith-interpretation

> Allah, the Exalted and Glorious, created the clay on Saturday and He
> created the mountains on Sunday and He created the trees on Monday and
> He created the things entailing labour on Tuesday and created light on
> Wednesday and He caused the animals to spread on Thursday and created
> Adam (peace be upon him) after 'Asr on Friday; the last creation at
> the last hour of the hours of Friday, i. e. between afternoon and
> night. This hadith is narrated through another chain of transmitters. [[Muslim 2789](https://sunnah.com/muslim/52/10)]

Day/Night/Hour are concepts which we use in the context of earth rotation around the sun! When earth is facing the sun during rotation, it is day and when it is not, it is night! We are dependant on the earth rotation for day/night/hour.

I know there is a Quranic verse which says 50,000 days of Humans is like 1 day according to God but the day mean "period" and it has got nothing to do with "day/night of Humans". The Hadith specifically mentions day names such as "Monday", "Tuesday" and concepts like "hours".

I was wondering, how can the concept of day-time/night-time & days like "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", etc can be applied to God?

Answer (score 1):

The Hadith is a variant of the Quranic Verse 41:9-12.
The creation «in 6 days» is already contained in the Torah.

You were citing Al-Ma`arij 70:4

> The angels and the Spirit ascend unto Him in a Day whereof the span is fifty thousand years.

We all know much better now than in the times of the Prophet ﷺ the truth behind it: We should not think that the time dimensions of God are our time dimensions.

You ask: I was wondering, how can the concept of day-time/night-time & days like "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", etc can be applied to God?

In fact, it is rather the other way around; it deals with the question: How can the «days» of God be applied to us humans?

For sure it is telling us that we should adore Him the Creator every day of the week.
It connects Friday afternoon to the time of Creation of men (by the way in full alignment with the Jewish tradition although they do not have a special Asr prayer on Friday). As to the other days, I suppose but do not actually see the wisdom behind it; maybe you see it...